# Rep for questions

Tags: discussion

As I understand it, folks are going to get their rep for questions adjusted. This has already happened for some users. When will this process be complete?

Comment: I think the process is already complete, why don’t you think so?

Comment: @user067531 I've had no change in rep that I've noticed and seen no noticable jump in other users who have asked lots of questions, for example Mari-LouA.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339417/which-users-gained-the-most-reputation-by-the-rewarding-the-question-askers-ch

Comment: You earned 1510 rep. points as a question asker: https://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/1151034/reputation-gained-by-2019-11-13-change while Mari-Lou earned 12974 rep. points https://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/1151034/reputation-gained-by-2019-11-13-change

Comment: The question rep tally has meant I have moved ahead a considerable number of places. I had about 65k and now it's close to 80K. My username appears among the first ten users, in the "all time" category, and the reason for this is because  my questions sometimes had more upvotes than many of the posted answers, ergo the "leap". Not that I care anymore. Stack Exchange is melting and dissolving in the Internet cauldron as we speak. It is but a small stale stock cube.

Comment: Did not see Josh's comments earlier. The numbers seem right.

Comment: @Mari-LouA - though you have good reason to feel disappointed, I think you, as well as many other users, took SE too seriously.

Comment: Oh, wow. Just noticed your username, Araucaria,  changed. You've quit the site? Big loss for everyone, as for Monica being reinstated...don't hold your breath. Meta SE has become a gladiator arena: suspensions, questions even remotely connected to Monica are closed, locked, and/or deleted on a regular basis. The site is ill and the surgeons keep chopping off limbs instead of finding a remedy for the sickness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The change was announced [November 13, 2019](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/11/13/were-rewarding-the-question-askers/) and it took [a couple of days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/338199/323179) for everything to sync up. But that was still weeks ago, so I guess you just didn't notice.

The change was retroactive, so it's like upvotes on questions were *always* worth 10 points. Therefore, there's no sudden jump in anyone's reputation graph.

Take Yoichi Oishi, for example (who probably gained the most from this, at least on this site):

- [35,124 rep](https://web.archive.org/web/20190702031311/https://english.stackexchange.com/users/3119/yoichi-oishi) on July 2, 2019
- [68,121 rep](https://web.archive.org/web/20191205025244/https://english.stackexchange.com/users/3119/yoichi-oishi) on December 4, 2019 (today)
  ≈ 33k rep gained

Glorfindel [wrote a query](https://data.stackexchange.com/english/query/1151034/reputation-gained-by-2019-11-13-change) so that you can estimate how much reputation you gained from the change.